# How to render HTML Template as response from json in react js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, reactjs

My api response is

```
{
"content" : "<div><p>Some random text</p></div>"
}
```

I am passing the html template as value in json response content.
In my application then I am trying to render the content but the output is

My output : `<div><p>Some random text</p></div>`

Actual output should be : `Some random text`

Can anyone guide what I am missing out ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also checkout [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to set innerHTML for HTML you get as string in response.

```
...
return (
  ...
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.content }} />
  ...
)
...
```

Comment: This solves the issue but the developer should be aware of cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks and therefore only use this in case the source of the data is trusted like something managed by app administrators.

Answer (score 0):

In order to converts raw HTML to a React DOM structure you need a library: [html-to-react](https://github.com/aknuds1/html-to-react)